# C# interop with COM has memory leak in multithread mode while single thread does not

Tags: .net, multithreading, com, memory-leaks

I wrote a C# console application to call a unmanaged COM interop. If I use single thread mode there is no memory leak. But when I use multi thread do interop with COM concurrently, there is huge memory leak. Both way have the same intereop count.
  I'm sure I'm using MTA mode, does COM allocate extra memory when using multi thread, like some work during thread context switch?

Comment: How do you detect this memory leak? And can you provide some more details on how you instantiate and dispose your objects?

Comment: I read Pysical and Virtual Memory from taskmgr and ProcessXP. Thing is, I create and release objects using COM and I write in each thread to a variable owns by the same thread.

Comment: Sure, using a single-threaded COM server in an MTA thread produces lots of overhead.  An STA thread just to give the server a safe home.  Plus a bunch of temporary buffers needed to marshal method arguments.  Should be a lot slower too.  And no concurrency, everything is serialized to this one STA thread.

Comment: @Hans, I don't understand. Do you main MTA is better? I'm using MTA already.